# How to use Should.js assertion library with Phantomjs-mocha testing framework

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, mocha.js, should.js

In my application i need to use Phantomjs-mocha testing framework to test my application node js code.So i have installed Should js assertion library.While running some example code i'm getting following error.Can anyone help me to resolve this issue

While running the below code i'm getting following error

```
    Failed to start mocha: Init timeout
```

testing.js

```
  var user = {
              name: 'tj',
              pets: ['tobi', 'loki', 'jane', 'bandit']
             };

  user.should.be.a('object').and.have.property('name', 'tj');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `be` fails, I should suppose that `should` is `undefined` and therefore there some problems in the way you imported `should.js` in your code.
Maybe check that the order of the `<script>` tags is correct: should.js modifies the object prototype, so it should be imported before your own objects are generated.

Comment: im trying the above code in Node js.After requiring the should as var should=require('should'); also i'm getting the same error

Comment: Oh, sorry I should have guessed about node.js. Can you confirm that `user.should` is undefined?

Comment: You can increase the timeout in the `mocha.setup()` call (not sure is the same timeout though...) or in the command line parameters, according to how you're using it.

Comment: im running this program with mocha-phantomjs as -- mocha-phantomjs testing.js.So i didn't included mocha in my app.

Comment: It should take the `-t` or `--timeout` parameter:

    mocha-phantomjs -t 10000 testing.js